# Can You assign a value A to a value B given two sets of data in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am very new to MatLab and have the following problem: I have 2 arrays with a lot of integers, and I would like to be able to assign any given data point from one array to another. Example:

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3]
array2 = [2, 4, 6]
```

So if I have a data from array1, in this case, I would be able to say `array1*2 = array2`. There are different ways to solve this, and I have two arrays with about 100k elements each. I need to divide the data into smaller segments and then create an average for each, so that I may be able to derive that for array1*X ~ array2. I need a good estimation, the example above just doesnt do it any justice. Thanks for the help

Comment: `array2 = array1.*2`?

Comment: Please have a look at the [Getting Started](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) tutorial.

Comment: The problem isnt as easy as it seems. There are different ways to solve this, and I have two arrays with about 100k elements each. I need to divide the data into smaller segments and then create an average for each, so that I may be able to derive that for array1*X ~ array2. I need a good estimation, the example above just doesnt do it any justice.

Comment: The **point** of an example is to do your real situation justice! If you don't think your own example is good enough, then give a better one. The more detail you give, the more complete and accurate answers you will get. For example, what do you expect your output to look like, how do you want to divide up your data, what are you trying to achieve, if a linear model isn't good enough then why a segmented linear model over a more sophisticated fitting method?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to estimate X in your formula: 
`array1*X = array2`
If you devide you get the estimate for each value, than take the mean to have an estimator of X

```
mean(double(array2)./double(array1))
```

You worry about the 100k values, 200k values in total. This is not big for Matlab. Concider that each value takes up 8 bytes. 1600kB is not much for a computer.

You could also fit it with a simple linear regression model

```
sum(array1.*array2) / sum(array1.^2)
```

Comment: Thank you, this comes closer to the answer im looking for. I tried something similar but since there is so much data, such a very rough estimation does not work. I hoped matlab would have such a build in function to come up with a better solution for such problems.

Comment: I don't see why you say there is much data. People who do image analysis have 2.073.600 pixels in a single fullHD frame. I added a linear regression model.

Comment: Because having the mean of 100k integers doesn't help to correlate small segments, when trying to solve an equation like this : arrayelement1*X = arrayelement2, you will be way off if you put the mean for X as you did.

Comment: Then you need to be more specific about what you are trying to achieve, because this answers your original question!

Answer (score 0):

Let's try again. So you have 2x 100k points that have a relation y = b*x.
You want to find b for different segments of the 100k points.

```
x = randi([1 2^15-1],1,1E5,'uint16'); %demo data
y = x.*2;
```

The two methods I gave before will yield 2:

```
x=double(x);y=double(y);
mean(y./x)
sum(x.*y) / sum(x.^2)
```

If you want to segment you can first cut the data in smaller parts

```
segment=1000; %nr datapoints / segment
N = length(x)/segment; %nr of segments
L = floor(rem(N,1)*segment); %nr of datapoints in last segment
N = floor(N);
xc=mat2cell(x,1,[repmat(segment,[1,N]),L]);
yc=mat2cell(y,1,[repmat(segment,[1,N]),L]);
if L==0,xc(end)=[];yc(end)=[];end
```

Now you can loop over xc and get the mean value

```
for ct = 1:length(xc)
    x = xc{ct};y=yc{ct};
    m(ct) = mean(y./x);
    m2(ct) = sum(x.*y) / sum(x.^2);
end
```